# Can I replace Document DB Generic Repository with Cosmos DB SDK 3.0?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have created generic repository for CRUD(Create,Read,Update and Delete) operations with Document DB assembly. I want to replace this with Cosmos DB SDK 3.0 SQL API.

Here is my cosmos db generic repository:

```
 public class CosmosDBRepository<T> : ICosmosDBRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly DocumentClient _client;

        private readonly string DatabaseId = "FleetHub";
        public static string CollectionId = GetAttributeCosmoDbCollection<T>(typeof(T));
        public CosmosDBRepository()
        {
            var endpoint = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("CosmoDbEndpoint");
            var authkey = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("CosmoDbAuthKey");
            try
            {
                if (endpoint == null || authkey == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("CosmoDbEndpoint or CosmoDbAuthKey could not be found in the config file, check your settings.");
                }

                if (_client == null)
                {
                    _client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpoint), authkey, connectionPolicy: new ConnectionPolicy { EnableEndpointDiscovery = false });
                }

                CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
                CreateCollectionIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }

        public async Task<T> GetItemAsync<T>(string id, string partitionkey) where T : class
        {
            try
            {

                Document document = await _client.ReadDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId, id), new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionkey) });
                return (T)(dynamic)document;
            }
            catch (DocumentClientException e)
            {
                if (e.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task<Document> CreateItemAsync<T>(T item) where T : class
        {
            return await _client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId), item);
        }
        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<T, object>> orderByDesc, int takeCount = -1)
            where T : class
        {
            var criteria = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
                        UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId), new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true })
                    .Where(predicate)
                    .OrderByDescending(orderByDesc)
                    .AsDocumentQuery();

            IDocumentQuery<T> query = criteria;

            List<T> results = new List<T>();
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                if (takeCount > -1 && results.Count >= takeCount)
                {
                    break;
                }
                results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
            }

            return results;
        }

        public async Task<Document> UpdateItemAsync<T>(string id, T item) where T : class
        {
            return await _client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId, id), item);
        }
        private async Task CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                await _client.ReadDatabaseAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(DatabaseId));
            }
            catch (DocumentClientException e)
            {
                if (e.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                    await _client.CreateDatabaseAsync(new Database { Id = DatabaseId });
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        private async Task CreateCollectionIfNotExistsAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                await _client.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync(
                            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId));
            }
            catch (DocumentClientException e)
            {

            }
        }

        private string GetPartitionKeyAttributeCosmoDbCollection(Type t)
        {
            // Get instance of the attribute.
            CosmoDBCollection attribute =
                (CosmoDBCollection)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(t, typeof(CosmoDBCollection));

            if (attribute == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("The attribute CosmoDbCollection was not found.");
            }
            return attribute.PartitionKey;
        }
        private static string GetAttributeCosmoDbCollection<T>(Type t) where T : class
        {
            CosmoDBCollection attribute =
                (CosmoDBCollection)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(t, typeof(CosmoDBCollection));
            return attribute.Name;
        }
    }
```

Can I Create generic repository with Cosmos DB SDK 3.0 SQL? Or I need to use Document DB assembly only for to create generic repository.
Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you can.Please refer to these documents:

[Quickstart: Build a .NET console app to manage Azure Cosmos DB SQL API resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-sql-api-dotnet)

[Azure Cosmos DB.NET V3 SDK (Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos) examples for the SQL API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-dotnet-v3sdk-samples)

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Links age/change/expire; also, these require the OP to go offsite to learn about something - nothing specific here. If you want to share a link, you can do that in a comment under the question (you have enough rep to do so).

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @SteveZhao Could you please share some sample code which will fit in my current scenario?